# How to have a User Account for different entities in Spring JPA?

Tags: spring, jpa, model, user-accounts

I'm making a system (using Spring + JPA with MySQL) that shows the best applicants for a certain job offer. The `company` and the `applicants` have their respective `user account`, and with that, they can fill in their `personal/company information` and their `job profile/job offer conditions`. With that, the system should match the job conditions (like 3+ years of experience in C) with the applicant's job profile.

[image: Sample class diagram]

My problem is that the User Account is created first, and should be independent, but these two different entities (Applicant and Company), with different attributes, are using it. So if I do something like create an `applicant` and `company` in the User Account, one of them will be always null.

How can I solve this? I guess the problem would be something like: how to implement a user account that can hold data from different entities that have different attributes (therefore, can't be grouped)? (In fact, I need one more entity, but I tried to simplify it to illustrate the problem more clearly).

Comment: the way i understand this user can play role of Applicant/Company and you already have Role entity to resolve that why can't you join User with Role always to determine the if its Applicant/Company?

Comment: I was seeing role just as a Spring Security implementation, and separate it from the fact of being an Applicant or Company, because those classes just have "personal" information, not permissions, but you're right, in some way, they are roles, which also have permissions. I'll join them, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should make marker interface, like `public interface UserAccountable` or smth. Implement this interface in your `Applicant` and `Company` classes. Then you can make a field in UserAccount class, like `private UserAccountable someUser;` and throught setters and getters you can assign and get this variable to Applicant or Company.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work in JPA because I don't know how to annotate the interface UserAccountable so it gets recognized by Spring and it doesn't require implementation like a Repository.
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.example.demo.model.UserAccount.user, referenced property unknown: com.example.demo.model.UserAccountable.userAccount

Answer (score 0):

I found what I needed here: https://thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/

The problem was the mapping, not the class design per se. I could create interfaces and abstract classes to solve it in the Java world, but in the SQL world that's not possible, so the mapping is the key. In this case, I was looking for the **Joined table** mapping, but I realized I needed it just to not have null fields in my `UserAccount`, because I don't need a polymorphic query (e.g. give me the names of every 'user type' (`Person`, `Company`)), and it would be too costly performance wise to implement it that way, so I'll trade off space for performance, and I'll just reference all three user types in the `User Account`, leaving two of those three fields null forever.

PS: Single table mapping won't help because I do need to use `not null` conditions.